# C++ std::enable_if differentiate between floating point and signed number?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae

How can I make the following differentiate between signed numbers and floating point numbers?

```
template<class T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_signed<T>::value>::type* = nullptr >
const char* GetTypeName(T t)
{
    if (std::numeric_limits<T>::max() == std::numeric_limits<signed char>::max())
        return "int8";
    else if (std::numeric_limits<T>::max() == std::numeric_limits<signed short>::max())
        return "int16";
    else if (std::numeric_limits<T>::max() == std::numeric_limits<signed int>::max())
        return "int32";
    else if (std::numeric_limits<T>::max() == std::numeric_limits<signed long long>::max())
        return "int64";
    else
        return nullptr;
}

template<class T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_unsigned<T>::value>::type* = nullptr >
const char* GetTypeName(T t)
{
    if (std::numeric_limits<T>::max() == std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::max())
        return "uint8";
    else if (std::numeric_limits<T>::max() == std::numeric_limits<unsigned short>::max())
        return "uint16";
    else if (std::numeric_limits<T>::max() == std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max())
        return "uint32";
    else if (std::numeric_limits<T>::max() == std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max())
        return "uint64";
    else
        return nullptr;
}

template<class T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value>::type* = nullptr >
const char* GetTypeName(T t)
{
    if (std::numeric_limits<T>::max() == std::numeric_limits<Float32>::max())
        return "float";
    else if (std::numeric_limits<T>::max() == std::numeric_limits<Float64>::max())
        return "double";
    else
        return nullptr;
}
```

Works perfectly with integral types but it cannot differentiate between signed numbers and floating point numbers:

```
// Works as expected
std::string tsig = GetTypeName<signed char>(static_cast<signed char>(0));
std::string tsig = GetTypeName<signed short>(static_cast<signed short>(0));
std::string tsig = GetTypeName<signed int>(static_cast<signed int>(0));
std::string tsig = GetTypeName<signed long long>(static_cast<signed long long>(0));

// Works as expected
std::string tsig = GetTypeName<unsigned char>(static_cast<unsigned char>(0));
std::string tsig = GetTypeName<unsigned short>(static_cast<unsigned short>(0));
std::string tsig = GetTypeName<unsigned int>(static_cast<unsigned int>(0));
std::string tsig = GetTypeName<unsigned long long>(static_cast<unsigned long long>(0));

// This is ambiguous!
std::string tsig = GetTypeName<float>(static_cast<float>(0));
std::string tsig = GetTypeName<double>(static_cast<double>(0));
```

Comment: Most probably because `float and double` are signed and floating point. In the overload resolution any of the 2 overload are equally good and there is ambiguity.

Comment: Are you trying to emulate the workings of [`std::is_same<T1,T2>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same)?

Comment: I believe it is undefined behavior to build a `std::string` from a null `char const*`, therefore I would advise to avoid calling `std::string s = GetTypeName(...);` at present. Switching `GetTypeName` to returning an empty string `""` (and possibly switching its return type to `std::string`) would be the easiest cure.

Comment: You know `long long` can be longer than 64 bit, and `int` can be shorter than 32 bits? Better use [`uintxx_t` from `<cstdint>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint)

Comment: Why are you doing this? - You might invent some numerical_traits, instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`std::is_floating_point`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_floating_point) trait along with `std::is_signed`.

```
template<class T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value>::type* = nullptr >
const char* GetTypeName(T t)
{
  // called for floating point types
}

template<class T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_signed<T>::value &&
                                          !std::is_floating_point<T>::value>::type* = nullptr >
const char* GetTypeName(T t)
{
  // called for signed integral types
}
```

---

Your example can be reimplemented using overload resolution too, which avoids all the `if-else if`s and `numeric_limits` verbosity.

```
template<typename T>
const char *GetTypeName(T) { return "<unknown>"; }

const char *GetTypeName(signed char) { return "int8"; }
const char *GetTypeName(signed short) { return "int16"; }
const char *GetTypeName(signed int) { return "int32"; }
const char *GetTypeName(signed long) { return "int64"; }

std::cout << GetTypeName(static_cast<signed char>(0)) << std::endl;
std::cout << GetTypeName(static_cast<signed short>(0)) << std::endl;
std::cout << GetTypeName(static_cast<signed int>(0)) << std::endl;
std::cout << GetTypeName(static_cast<signed long>(0)) << std::endl;
std::cout << GetTypeName(static_cast<signed long long>(0)) << std::endl;
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/de716b05f2270c20)

Comment: Thanks for the correct answer but I actually went with Matthieu's version.

Comment: @SanduLiviuCatalin Took me a few minutes cause I was in the middle of something else, but I just added the same solution, before even seeing that Matthieu had already suggested the same thing :) And his suggestion to use the typedefs from `<cstdint>` is the better way to do it too.

Comment: I tried this first but I forgot about the static_cast() for the parameter and it didn't worked. One more sub-question: Would it have any effect if I made the function constexpr? From what I could understand it would take place at compile time.

Comment: @Sandu `constexpr` would only help if the arguments to the function are known at compile time. But for something this trivial, I doubt it'll make a difference because the compiler knows which overload to select, and will inline the contents anyway. Also, if you know the arguments at compile time, why do you need these sets of functions? This is starting to sound like an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), what are you trying to do?

Comment: "why do you need these sets of functions?" let's just say that it involves multiple templated function which need this kind of information. Those functions are made to avoid repetitions. Too much to get in detail here. And thanks for the `constexpr` tip.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, `enable_if` is not exactly easily extensible.

In general, you need to tweak the signature of *each and every* overload so that they are mutually exclusive. This would mean adding `!std::is_floating_point<T>::value` to the condition for signed and unsigned integrals.

---

In your particular case, though:

```
#include <cstdint>

char const* GetTypeName(...) { return nullptr; }

char const* GetTypeName(int8_t) { return "int8"; }
char const* GetTypeName(int16_t) { return "int16"; }
char const* GetTypeName(int32_t) { return "int32"; }
char const* GetTypeName(int64_t) { return "int64"; }

// etc...
```

would work without all that complicated machinery.

Comment: Good one. Sometimes one really has to take a step back to avoid over-engineering things.

Comment: The header for the types is `<cstdint>`.

Comment: This is what I've tried the first time but I forgot to do a static_cast() in the function parameter and and it didn't worked. As shown in @Praetorian 's example. Thank you.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Good call, always worth mentioning which header things come from